# Script error in angular-file-upload.js

Tags: angularjs, cloudinary, angular-file-upload

I get 'Script error in the below js' file .This is the file downloaded using bower install from cloudinary-angular from git hub. Whats the error here?

**angular-file-upload.js**

/**!
     * AngularJS file upload/drop directive with http post and progress
     * @author  Danial  
     * @version 1.6.6
     */
    (function() {

```
var angularFileUpload = angular.module('angularFileUpload', []);

angularFileUpload.service('$upload', ['$http', '$q', '$timeout', function($http, $q, $timeout) {
    function sendHttp(config) {
        config.method = config.method || 'POST';
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        config.transformRequest = config.transformRequest || function(data, headersGetter) {
            if (window.ArrayBuffer && data instanceof window.ArrayBuffer) {
                return data;
            }
            return $http.defaults.transformRequest[0](data, headersGetter);
        };
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest.__isShim) {
            config.headers['__setXHR_'] = function() {
                return function(xhr) {
                    if (!xhr) return;
                    config.__XHR = xhr;
                    config.xhrFn && config.xhrFn(xhr);
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                        deferred.notify(e);
                    }, false);
                    //fix for firefox not firing upload progress end, also IE8-9
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
                        if (e.lengthComputable) {
                            deferred.notify(e);
                        }
                    }, false);
                };
            };
        }

        $http(config).then(function(r){deferred.resolve(r)}, function(e){deferred.reject(e)}, function(n){deferred.notify(n)});

        var promise = deferred.promise;
        promise.success = function(fn) {
            promise.then(function(response) {
                fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
            });
            return promise;
        };

        promise.error = function(fn) {
            promise.then(null, function(response) {
                fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
            });
            return promise;
        };

        promise.progress = function(fn) {
            promise.then(null, null, function(update) {
                fn(update);
            });
            return promise;
        };
        promise.abort = function() {
            if (config.__XHR) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    config.__XHR.abort();
                });
            }
            return promise;
        };
        promise.xhr = function(fn) {
            config.xhrFn = (function(origXhrFn) {
                return function() {
                    origXhrFn && origXhrFn.apply(promise, arguments);
                    fn.apply(promise, arguments);
                }
            })(config.xhrFn);
            return promise;
        };

        return promise;
    }

    this.upload = function(config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        config.headers['Content-Type'] = undefined;
        config.transformRequest = config.transformRequest || $http.defaults.transformRequest;
        var formData = new FormData();
        var origTransformRequest = config.transformRequest;
        var origData = config.data;
        config.transformRequest = function(formData, headerGetter) {
            if (origData) {
                if (config.formDataAppender) {
                    for (var key in origData) {
                        var val = origData[key];
                        config.formDataAppender(formData, key, val);
                    }
                } else {
                    for (var key in origData) {
                        var val = origData[key];
                        if (typeof origTransformRequest == 'function') {
                            val = origTransformRequest(val, headerGetter);
                        } else {
                            for (var i = 0; i < origTransformRequest.length; i++) {
                                var transformFn = origTransformRequest[i];
                                if (typeof transformFn == 'function') {
                                    val = transformFn(val, headerGetter);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        formData.append(key, val);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (config.file != null) {
                var fileFormName = config.fileFormDataName || 'file';

                if (Object.prototype.toString.call(config.file) === '[object Array]') {
                    var isFileFormNameString = Object.prototype.toString.call(fileFormName) === '[object String]';
                    for (var i = 0; i < config.file.length; i++) {
                        formData.append(isFileFormNameString ? fileFormName : fileFormName[i], config.file[i], 
                                (config.fileName && config.fileName[i]) || config.file[i].name);
                    }
                } else {
                    formData.append(fileFormName, config.file, config.fileName || config.file.name);
                }
            }
            return formData;
        };

        config.data = formData;

        return sendHttp(config);
    };

    this.http = function(config) {
        return sendHttp(config);
    }
}]);

angularFileUpload.directive('ngFileSelect', [ '$parse', '$timeout', function($parse, $timeout) {
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
        var fn = $parse(attr['ngFileSelect']);
        if (elem[0].tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'input' || (elem.attr('type') && elem.attr('type').toLowerCase()) !== 'file') {
            var fileElem = angular.element('<input type="file">')
            for (var i = 0; i < elem[0].attributes.length; i++) {
                fileElem.attr(elem[0].attributes[i].name, elem[0].attributes[i].value);
            }
            if (elem.attr("data-multiple")) fileElem.attr("multiple", "true");
            fileElem.css("top", 0).css("bottom", 0).css("left", 0).css("right", 0).css("width", "100%").
                    css("opacity", 0).css("position", "absolute").css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=0)');
            elem.append(fileElem);
            if (fileElem.parent()[0] != elem[0]) {
                //fix #298
                elem.wrap('<span>');
                elem.css("z-index", "-1000")
                elem.parent().append(fileElem);
                elem = elem.parent();
            }
            if (elem.css("position") === '' || elem.css("position") === 'static') {
                elem.css("position", "relative");
            }
            elem = fileElem;
        }
        elem.bind('change', function(evt) {
            var files = [], fileList, i;
            fileList = evt.__files_ || evt.target.files;
            if (fileList != null) {
                for (i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                    files.push(fileList.item(i));
                }
            }
            $timeout(function() {
                fn(scope, {
                    $files : files,
                    $event : evt
                });
            });
        });
        // removed this since it was confusing if the user click on browse and then cancel #181
//      elem.bind('click', function(){
//          this.value = null;
//      });

        // removed because of #253 bug
        // touch screens
//      if (('ontouchstart' in window) ||
//              (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0)) {
//          elem.bind('touchend', function(e) {
//              e.preventDefault();
//              e.target.click();
//          });
//      }
    };
} ]);

angularFileUpload.directive('ngFileDropAvailable', [ '$parse', '$timeout', function($parse, $timeout) {
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
        if ('draggable' in document.createElement('span')) {
            var fn = $parse(attr['ngFileDropAvailable']);
            $timeout(function() {
                fn(scope);
            });
        }
    };
} ]);

angularFileUpload.directive('ngFileDrop', [ '$parse', '$timeout', '$location', function($parse, $timeout, $location) {
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
        if ('draggable' in document.createElement('span')) {
            var leaveTimeout = null;
            elem[0].addEventListener("dragover", function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                $timeout.cancel(leaveTimeout);
                if (!elem[0].__drag_over_class_) {
                    if (attr['ngFileDragOverClass'] && attr['ngFileDragOverClass'].search(/\) *$/) > -1) {
                        dragOverClassFn = $parse(attr['ngFileDragOverClass']);
                        var dragOverClass = dragOverClassFn(scope, {
                            $event : evt
                        });                 
                        elem[0].__drag_over_class_ = dragOverClass; 
                    } else {
                        elem[0].__drag_over_class_ = attr['ngFileDragOverClass'] || "dragover";
                    }
                }
                elem.addClass(elem[0].__drag_over_class_);
            }, false);
            elem[0].addEventListener("dragenter", function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
            }, false);
            elem[0].addEventListener("dragleave", function(evt) {
                leaveTimeout = $timeout(function() {
                    elem.removeClass(elem[0].__drag_over_class_);
                    elem[0].__drag_over_class_ = null;
                }, attr['ngFileDragOverDelay'] || 1);
            }, false);
            var fn = $parse(attr['ngFileDrop']);
            elem[0].addEventListener("drop", function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                elem.removeClass(elem[0].__drag_over_class_);
                elem[0].__drag_over_class_ = null;
                extractFiles(evt, function(files) {
                    fn(scope, {
                        $files : files,
                        $event : evt
                    });                 
                });
            }, false);

            function isASCII(str) {
                return /^[\000-\177]*$/.test(str);
            }

            function extractFiles(evt, callback) {
                var files = [], items = evt.dataTransfer.items;
                if (items && items.length > 0 && items[0].webkitGetAsEntry && $location.protocol() != 'file' && 
                        items[0].webkitGetAsEntry().isDirectory) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        var entry = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
                        if (entry != null) {
                            //fix for chrome bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=149735
                            if (isASCII(entry.name)) {
                                traverseFileTree(files, entry);
                            } else if (!items[i].webkitGetAsEntry().isDirectory) {
                                files.push(items[i].getAsFile());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    var fileList = evt.dataTransfer.files;
                    if (fileList != null) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                            files.push(fileList.item(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
                (function waitForProcess(delay) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        if (!processing) {
                            callback(files);
                        } else {
                            waitForProcess(10);
                        }
                    }, delay || 0)
                })();
            }

            var processing = 0;
            function traverseFileTree(files, entry, path) {
                if (entry != null) {
                    if (entry.isDirectory) {
                        var dirReader = entry.createReader();
                        processing++;
                        dirReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                                traverseFileTree(files, entries[i], (path ? path : "") + entry.name + "/");
                            }
                            processing--;
                        });
                    } else {
                        processing++;
                        entry.file(function(file) {
                            processing--;
                            file._relativePath = (path ? path : "") + file.name;
                            files.push(file);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
} ]);

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to require '$parse', '$timeout before this module, which are reffered inside this module.

Answer (score 1):

More context is needed to understand the issue here, for example the way/order the files are included in the page. Specifically, you should verify the correct ordering of the JS files, as shown here:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/blob/master/samples/photo_album/app/index.html#L21

Comment: Yes order of files were also required to be proper